# Multiple Exceptions In java

Tags: java, exception

There are 3 different types of outputs , randomly . Can someone explain   why the outputs are these?

**Out1** => "m1_1
m1_3
m1_4
m2_1
m2_3
m3_1
m3_3" Case Exception3.

**Out2**=>"m1_1
m2_2
m2_3
m3_1
m3_3" Case Exception2.

**Out3**=>"m1_1
m3_2
m3_3" Case Exception1.

Classes:

```
class Exception1 extends Exception {
}

class Exception2 extends Exception {
}

class Exception3 extends Exception {
}

public class C {

  public void method1() throws Exception1, Exception2 {
    try {
        System.out.println(Math.random()+"\n");
        System.out.println("m1_1");
        //some code here that will randomly throw Exception1,2,or3
        if (Math.random() <= 0.3) {
            throw new Exception1();
        }
        if (Math.random() < 0.6) {
            throw new Exception2();
        }
        if (Math.random() < 0.9) {
            throw new Exception3();
        }
        System.out.println("m1_2");
    } catch (Exception3 e3) {
        System.out.println("m1_3");
    }
    System.out.println("m1_4");
  }

  public void method2() throws Exception1 {
    try {
        method1();
        System.out.println("m2_1");
    } catch (Exception2 e2) {

        System.out.println("m2_2");
    }
    System.out.println("m2_3");
  }

  public void method3() {
    try {
        method2();
        System.out.println("m3_1");
    } catch (Exception1 e1) {

        System.out.println("m3_2");
    }
    System.out.println("m3_3");
  }
}
```

class Tester {

```
public static void main(String[] a) {
    C c = new C();
    c.method3();
}
```

}

Comment: This looks like a homework-type of assignment, but my guess it is a valid exercise. You should have a look at how java exceptions works (focus on throw/try/catch behavior). Depending of which exception is triggered, the path of catchs will be different, and then the `println` calls that are actually executed is different.

Comment: What do you know about exception handling and specially about catching vs not catching an exception in a method?

Comment: Did you try stepping through this with a debugger?

Answer (score -1):

Your two problems are that you have multiple calls of Math.random, and multiple ifs that fit one condition.

You would need to get 1 number from Math.random() and use that e.g:

```
double rand = Math.random();
```

Then, you would need to switch the overlapping ifs to else ifs, since if rand was 0.1 it would fit all 3 if conditions.

So in the end method1 should look something like this:

```
public void method1() throws Exception1, Exception2 {
    try {
        double rand = Math.random();
        System.out.println(rand+"\n");
        System.out.println("m1_1");
        //some code here that will randomly throw Exception1,2,or3
        if (rand <= 0.3) {
            throw new Exception1();
        }
        else if (rand < 0.6) {
            throw new Exception2();
        }
        else if (rand < 0.9) {
            throw new Exception3();
        }
        System.out.println("m1_2");
    } catch (Exception3 e3) {
        System.out.println("m1_3");
    }
    System.out.println("m1_4");
}
```

Comment: This doesn’t answer the question, it’s more of a code review

Comment: It answers the question by giving the reason for the odd outputs in the first line

Comment: That’s not the question

Comment: @AleksW thanks for your answer ,  i dont want to change the code . I know what the Math.random() does , i understand the code but  i just simply ask  "how it works and why it goes like this " . Thank you again